# InsertOne an array of object into Mongodb node.js not working

Tags: node.js, reactjs

When I do the insert below, {address, address2, city, state, zipcode } does not get inserted. Not sure what is missing here. It gets inserted into the database with null values. 
This is my response back.
{
    "_id": "5e7968210fb5ab4f60d17f62",
    "taxitem": "Federal-Income-Tax",
    "firstname": "Ronald",
    "lastname": "Grover",
    "dateofbirth": "12/09/2009",
    "userdetails": [
        {
            "address": null,
            "address2": null,
            "city": null,
            "state": null,
            "zipcode": null
        }
    ]
}

```js
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';
import path from 'path';

const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/build')));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const withDB = async (operations, res) => {
    try {
        const client = await MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017', { useUnifiedTopology:true, useNewUrlParser: true });
        const db = client.db('TaxApp_BackEnd');
    
        await operations(db);
    
        client.close();
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error connecting to db', error });
    }
}
app.post('/api/taxes/:taxitem/add-user', (req,res) => {
     const {firstname, lastname, dateofbirth, address, address2, city, state, zipcode } = req.body;
     const taxitem = req.params.taxitem;
     console.log(req.body);
    
     withDB(async (db) => {
         try{
         const taxInfo = await db.collection('taxes');
         await db.collection('taxes').insertOne({ taxitem,firstname,lastname, dateofbirth, userdetails:[{ address, address2, city, state, zipcode  }] 
         });
         const insertedTax = await db.collection('taxes').findOne({ firstname, lastname });

         res.status(200).json(insertedTax);
         } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error inserting to db', error });
      }
     }, res);
});
```

Comment: Are you destructuring request body correctly? Aren't the `userdetails` included in a `userdetails` property in the body?

Comment: How do I destructure  the request body correctly?

Comment: I am not able to tell if you don't show the `req.body` structure the way you did with the `response`.

Comment: {
 "taxitem": "Federal-Income-Tax",
 "firstname": "Ronald",
 "lastname": "Great",
 "dateofbirth": "12/09/2009",
 "userdetails":[{"address":"1905 Plum Grove Road","address2":"","city":"Aurora","state":"IL","zipcode":"60014"}]
 
}

Comment: above is the structure of the response object. Thanks for your assistence @Eggon

Comment: You did provide `response` structure in your question. I was asking for `req.body` structure now.